# Is Root Algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, precision

I create a function to determine if a number was a root (not sure if this is the right term) of another number.

```
def isRoot(n, root):
   return not math.log(n, root)%1
```

For the most part this works, but I've found I've had a floating point problem. For example if I do `isRoot(125,5)` I get `False`. After some troubleshooting, I found that the reason is because

```
>>> math.log(125,5)
3.0000000000000004
```

Even though the result should be `3`. So my question is, should I just use a different algorithm, one I'm not aware of? Or is there a way to ensure this will work correctly no matter how large of a number I use?

Comment: Maybe you'd have less problem with `def isSquare(root, n):`.

Comment: @Efferalgan That's not going to do what I need it to do...

Comment: I was merely suggesting the alternative approach that the answer proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to avoid the problem is with a different approach that avoids floating point math entirely.

```
def isRoot(n, root):
    return n <= 1 or (False if n % root != 0 else isRoot(n // root, root))
```

Comment: Surely I don't want `isRoot(0.5, 3)` to be true.

Comment: @AlexHall surely not. I was assuming the inputs would always be integers > 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on a floating point number being exactly equal to 0 (False) for your function to work. Generally speaking, you should avoid testing for equality when dealing with floating point numbers. Instead, it's better to set an acceptable tolerance level for the difference.

Try this instead:

```
def isRoot(n, root, epsilon=1e-10):
    test = math.log(n, root)%1
    return abs(test - int(round(test))) < epsilon
```

Comment: Remember that roundoff error can be low as well as high.

Comment: Taking the absolute value should account for that.

Comment: @MarkRansom is just looking for a number that is close enough, a valid way to handle this? It seems like there should be a more definite way of doing it.

Comment: No, taking the absolute value won't change anything - the result of `%1` will always be a number in the range `[0, 1)`. @Hoopdady yes it's a valid approach, it's just that this answer isn't 100% correct yet. And it fails when your numbers get large enough that the `log` is within your tolerance even if it's not a root.

Comment: Ah yes, you're absolutely right @MarkRansom. I realize now that absolute value doesn't actually do anything here, as `math.log()` has a domain error for negative numbers. Your approach above is much better, and it works for negative numbers.

Comment: Actually my code always returns `True` for negative numbers, which is wrong, but thanks for the compliment. And I'll give you another hint on how to fix your problem: what's `2.999999999999999%1`?

Comment: I see what you mean. Edited to fix that case.

Comment: The `int` is redundant but now I believe it works properly, at least for reasonably small values of `n`. Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def isRoot(n, root):
    power = 1
    while root ** power < n:
        power += 1
    return root ** power == n
```

If this is too slow you can also do a sort of binary search to reduce the number of checks.

Comment: I'm really looking for a one check solution. I've got it, I just need it to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the performance hit, you could look at the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module in the standard library. It's got arbitrary-precision numbers.

Comment: This problem can't be solved by throwing more precision at it.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, I think you're right. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Hoopdady: If your inputs are all going to be integers, just use integer math, something like Alex Hall's implementation. If your inputs could be floating-point, the idea of trying to do this at all with floating-point numbers is suspect. For floating-point input, your best option would probably be to write an `is_near_root` function and introduce a tolerance in the comparison, something like pault's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just round to an integer and verify:

```
def isRoot(n, root):
    power = int(round(math.log(n, root)))
    return root ** power == n
```